# XML for Analysis parser: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed

Tags: ssis, ssas, mdx

I do not have any issue for processing SSAS cubes through Management Studio; however I got the following error message when processing cube through SSIS packages

> XML for Analysis parser: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed

Any ideas?

Comment: What is SSIU? And how long does it take before the timeout error occurs?

Comment: @GregGalloway sorry for mispelling, it is ssis package

Comment: and how long does it take to receive the error?

Comment: @GregGalloway   Another  team uses ssis package  to process cube . I will get email from them to tell me something wrong with processing cube in the package and then I will process cube through Management Studio.  After I processing cube successfully, cube got processed successfully via ssis package. any idea

Answer (score 1):

full error text is

> Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or
>   ODBC error:  [DataSource.Error] AnalysisServices: XML for Analysis
>   parser:  The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was
>   completed.

Solution in parameter ServerTimeout in server properties
also ExternalCommandTimeout must be increase

[more about server settings](http://richardlees.blogspot.com/2012/01/analysis-services-configuration-options.html)

additional in BI Query you can specify CommandTimeout param

> = AnalysisServices.Database("localhost\developer", "Analysis Services Tutorial", [**CommandTimeout**=#duration(0,3,0,0)])